Help with Hybrid Homomorphic Encryption
I read in this paper here that symmetric ciphers like AES is not a good choice for Hybrid Homomorphic Encryption due to large multiplicative depth. I want to understand more about this statement. How is the multiplicative depth of AES computed? And why is it not compatible for this reason?
I tried looking into other papers but every other paper says the same line without any details into it. I cannot understand how you compute multiplicative depth of AES or symmetric ciphers

Do you know how to compute the multiplicative depth of other functions?

Yes, basically the number of multiplicative gates in an arithmetic circuit or and gates in Boolean. What I don’t understand is how AES adds to increase in depth? Is it due to modular exponentiations performed in AES?

It was 41, see FHE AES implementations...

What is 41? Could you please elaborate? And where should I see the implementations? Could you point to the source please?
